# Header status not working in php cgi

Tags: php, iis, header, cgi, status

Setting the `Status` header is not working in PHP CGI. I am using PHP on the IIS webserver.

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
header('Status: 404 Not Found');
```

Do you have any ideas why this might not be working?

Comment: "not working" isn't a very specific error. what is happening?

Comment: Thanks for reply. go to the internal server error page.

Comment: so you are saying it returns a 500 status rather than a 404?

Comment: yes, 500 status default error

Answer (score 1):

Simply sending a `Status` header from PHP does not make your webserver return it's default error page. You need to do this yourself. Either you generate the contents for an error page like you would render any other page, or you redirect to another URL and configure your webserver to display an error page for you.

For example, you could do this in PHP:

```
header('Location: /404.html');
```

Then configure your webserver to serve 404.html as a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks for reply. my req is not redirect the 404.html page if get the error display the same page and change the header status only(404 not found).